# HTML CSS target adjacent cells containing a class

Tags: html, css

I have a table with rows and cells, and inside each sell is an un-ordered list.

Some of these UL tags (Not the table TD cell) have a class applied to them which adds a red border to the ul, the problem is that I do not want a double border and so need to remove either the left border from all adjacent cells except the first or remove the right border on the first cell.

There may be several occurrences in the row of adjacent cells with the ul.class to add the borders, and there may be other cells in between which do not have the ul class.

This is a simple example of a very complex table, I have omitted the closing tags:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <ul class="flag">
    <td>
        <ul class="flag">
    <td>
        <ul>
    <td>
        <ul>
    <td>
        <ul class="flag">
    <td>
        <ul class="flag">
```

I have tried using the adjacent tag but that does not work:

```
ul.flag {
    border: 1px 1px 1px 1px
}

ul.flag + ul.flag {
    border: 1px 1px 1px 0
}
```

How can I target adjacent cells containing a tag with a particular class ?

Comment: The lists aren't adjacent, the cells are.

Answer (score 1):

First set border

```
td ul.flag {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Then remove the left-border of all child's except the first-child

```
td:not(:first-child) ul.flag{
   border-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't that only work if all of the flagged columns are contiguous ?, what if there are gaps with some cells not flagged in between ? - I just tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: will ul.flag comes after two blank ul or randomly ?

Comment: you can use something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3jyuco5v/)